# How can I make full-screen desktop applications only cover the snapped desktop?

Tags: windows-8, fullscreen, modern-ui

In Windows 8, you can "snap" two apps next to each other, and one of those apps can be the legacy Windows desktop environment. A convenient application for this (or so I thought) would be to snap a chat client, small browser, or other app while watching content in full-screen on the desktop.

The problem with this is that full screen desktop applications will take over the *entire* screen, even if the desktop is snapped to only occupy 3/4th of the display.

What I would like is some way to force "full screen" desktop apps to only cover the snapped desktop area, and to truly go full screen if the desktop is snapped to full-width. Is there some way to configure this?

If that didn't make sense, let me illustrate with pictures:

#### Desktop in snapped view with SU chat in mini-browser:

[image: snapped]

#### What happens when you click "full screen":

[image: full screen]

#### What I want to happen when I click "full screen" (note this is digitally altered, not a real screenshot)

[image: full screen snapped]

**Just to clarify, I'm using YouTube as an example, but I'd like to be able to do this for *any* program that goes full-screen.**

Comment: Good question. I think it may defeat most programs' notion of a full screen, meaning that they do not see the snapped frames as the screen, merely a constraint for the application window dimensions.

Comment: @HenningKlevjer true, but if I want it to be full screen, I can always close the snapped app on the side. It would be nice if there were a way for Windows to basically tell the application "yo, this screen is now 1024x768, OK? Great, go be full screen over there now!" As long as it's invisible to the application, I expect it would work fine. I'm just not sure if there is such a way.

Comment: The exception would be if it needed DirectX access (and possibly OpenGL) access in full-screen, like for games.

Comment: Absolutely! But it sounds like a mess-up-the-drivers kind of deal ;) (whoops, added my comment as answer)

Comment: @HenningKlevjer agreed, there would probably be some hurdles to overcome, which may be why this is not the default behavior. Hopefully there'll be some workaround though that doesn't break things too badly!

Comment: I guess this responsibility lies on the app itself to provide "such" full screen that is aware of presence of a snapped app. Think of it as default behavior, and then What if someone needs actual full screen. :) Now metro interface needs to redefine the definition of full-screen. ;-)

Comment: @Lamb if one wants the app to actually go _full_ screen though, they can easily just unsnap the desktop. It's akin to having dual monitors - full screen apps only cover the screen they're on, not both screens.

Comment: Some applications uses screen resolution as fullscreen width and height boundaries to show its content, for example I changed flashplayer fullscreen size to fit that space as you mentioned, it worked but video was just cropped, video didn't automatically resize to adjust to its new container size.

Comment: At least the behaviour is backwards compatible - if you dock a window to one of the edges in Windows XP (via Tooldock API), like the task bar, a full screen window will not cover it but a full screen app will...

Answer (score 2):

If all you require is to watch youtube videos, you can follow this recipe:

1. Enter this URI in your browser and remove as much as possible of the unimportant contents of the window (address bar, bookmarks, etc.): 
   `data:text/html;,<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="800" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dfiR1Rde7dI" frameborder="0"> </iframe>`
2. Adjust the `width` and `height` attributes to perfect the screen size.
3. Change the youtube video ID at the end of the `src`, after `/embed/`.
4. Enjoy

Comment: cool..In addition one can have some JavaScript bookmark to automate the process of extracting the `scr` and open new tab without any need to type anything manually.

Comment: That's a neat trick for YouTube, thanks! I would like a solution that works for _any_ full-screen program, but this is a cool tip.

Answer (score 2):

This coresponds to the application's `viewstate` and they way the browser handles plugins. I would call this is a bug in the software because it doesn't change a parameter called the `viewstate` as outlined [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Snap-Sample-2dc21ee3).

The browser should query Windows for the current viewstate and make the necissary adjustments.

The important implication is that the problem cannot be fixed without source level changes to the programs.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to open the video via the embedded video link.

1. Replace `watch?v=` with `v/` in the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   To make the embedded player behave the same as the fullscreen mode, add the following parameters at the end of the URL: `?showinfo=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1`
2. Then focus the address bar again and press <kbd>F11</kbd> to hide the browser UI and
   taskbar
   (not sure if this behaves correctly with the snapped desktop)

---

You can also save the following as a bookmark, which will then do the job for you:

> javascript:location.get=function(a){return(a=RegExp(encodeURIComponent(a)+"=([^&]*)&?").exec(location.search))?a[1]:null};location.get("v")&&(location.href="http://www.youtube.com/v/"+location.get("v")+"?showinfo=0&autoplay=1&autohide=1");

Comment: This doesn't work. Pressing F11 puts the browser into full screen mode, which covers the whole screen - exactly the problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @nhinkle As I said in my answer, I wasn't quite sure if F11 behaves accordingly. Apart from that, have you even tried the bookmark solution ?

Comment: It's a moot point - this solution doesn't really achieve what I want to do. It half-way works for YouTube videos, and doesn't work for anything else.

Comment: @nhinkle That's why I called it an alternative solution. I'm just wondering why Henning's answer recieves upvotes although it's basically the same as mine, just more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The free [WinMaxinumize](http://www.tovilevis.com/index.php?cat=development&sub=programs&id=7) application is supposed to address this problem, using a hotkey to
expand the active window over all unused desktop space.

A descriptive write-up is provided in this [ghacks article](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/01/31/winmaxinumize-expand-windows-over-unused-space/).

(Not having Windows 8, I cannot test.)

Comment: Interesting find, but doesn't seem to solve the problem at hand. I tested it on Windows 8 with a snapped app on the side. It properly maximizes a program across the snapped desktop area, but it doesn't do anything to help with making it full-screen. All the window chrome is still there.

Comment: What happens if you make the program go full-screen, then use the WinMaxinumize hotkey?

Comment: Another idea: Maybe combine this with another application such as [Winsplit-Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) or [Acer Gridvista](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Acer-Gridvista.shtml).